# Consuming a WSE-enabled Web Service in an ASP.NET 2.0 web site

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wse

I'm trying to consume a WSE enabled Web Service from an ASP.NET Web Site.

I've installed WSE 3.0, used the config tool to add WSE info to my web.config and then done an Add Web Reference.

I believe that the problem may be that this is a Web SITE, not a Web APPLICATION.  As such, the proxy class is generated at runtime, perhaps not adding the WSE magic.

I can access the proxy class from metadata, and it's of type System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol, which as far as I can tell doesn't have any WSE functionality.

I realize that this is all old technology, but I don't get to decide what the servers run :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong, proxy is generated when you are adding web reference.

Could you tell me how you are adding web reference to the website.

Please refer following article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5sds7a0b.aspx

> After you have located a Web service
>   for your application to access by
>   using the Add Web Reference dialog
>   box, **clicking the Add Reference
>   button will instruct Visual Studio to
>   download the service description to
>   the local machine and then generate a
>   proxy class for the chosen Web
>   service**. The proxy class will
>   contain methods for calling each
>   exposed Web service method both
>   synchronously and asynchronously. This
>   class is contained in the local .wsdl
>   file's code-behind file. For more
>   information, see Web References in
>   Visual Studio and Add Web Reference
>   Dialog Box.

Please refer following article - [How to Add a Web Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx)

Comment: That link refers to WCF, not to WSE.  WCF is not available for my project.

Comment: What .NET Framework version you are using.
What is the IDE you are using to consume a WSE service.

Comment: It's .NET 2.0.  I tried reinstalling WSE and creating a new web site.  The correct class is now generated at runtime with the Wse postfix.  Thanks for trying to help.